# Best way to decrease photo size without losing quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, image-quality, smartobject

I know the best way is to convert to a smart object but the problem is where I want to apply an action to my high quality image. I have two ways:

1. Decrease size. This reduces quality.
2. Convert to a smart object. But my action will not run, because my action needs the image to be the background layer.

Maybe you want to know why one of the ways is decrease photo size; the answer is because export size is over 2GB and I do not like to waste my hard disk capacity. Using a smart object a is good choice but the action does not accept smart objects.

Is there any way that a layer can be the background layer and also a smart object, so I can resize that with my requirement?

Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: Some twilight  here - Converting to smart object  and resizing it smaller do not make the file smaller than the full size original, because the full-size original still lurks under the hood. One uses smart objects for resizing, because if he later decides  to return to a bigger size, it will be possible without quality loss. Another reason may be to get several virtual different copies of one image - say 5 copies,, but only one takes plenty of storage. Explain a little, what your action does.

Comment: Could you provide an outline of the action you want to perform? Most anything in PS can be applied to a smart object, so I'm not understanding why you can't use a smart object in this scenario.

Comment: How big is the original photo file? Are you using a RAW format?

Comment: @Ce. i use of shimmer action bro

Comment: @user287001 i use of shimmer action. have you used it? maybe you know how can apply that on my smart object

Comment: @sajad Sevenstyles Shimmer accepts only the background. Your best bet without deep software hacking skills is to make a temporary copy and flatten it to be the backround.  Shimmer has no inbuilt capablity to affect on multilayer stuff. It needs a single bitmap as the target. The flattening and Shimmerizing process probably can be automated as a self recorded action, But remembering the interactive nature (need masking) of Shimmer no heavy time savings are available

Comment: @user287001 You're not wrong when saying 5 instances of a smart object can lower file sizes but this is often something that confuses and frustrates peoples who think this isn't so when looking at file sizes. Each instance will still store a preview, to scale, of the original that can often require similar storage space as the original. It only sees benefits when the instances are noticeably smaller.

Answer (score -1):

In photoshop
Open your image
Go to File > **Save for Web** (alt+shift+ctrl+S)

A pop box Go to right hand corner **Preset**
a drop down
Click on **JPEG Low**
And save with a new name

Comment: I suspect that the OP requires good quality, hence the size of the image.  A lossless format such as PNG may be more appropriate.

Comment: “Without losing quality” is literally right there in the title of the question. Saving for web, especially with JPEG Low, loses huge amounts of quality.